# common crawl error "the specified key does not exist"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download warc files from aws common crawl over https, which was working but for some reason when I tried recently I keep getting `the specified key does not exist` error.

when I test the index for a specific url I do get a response, but when I try to download the warc for each record I get the error.

here is the index url http://index.commoncrawl.org/CC-MAIN-2015-11-index?url=fivethirtyeight.com&matchType=domain&output=json to test, which shows many records that are formatted as follows:
`{"urlkey": "com,fivethirtyeight)/", "timestamp": "20150228172316", "url": "http://fivethirtyeight.com/", "length": "17426", "filename": "crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2015-11/segments/1424936462009.45/warc/CC-MAIN-20150226074102-00094-ip-10-28-5-156.ec2.internal.warc.gz", "digest": "FXI6SYLZSAFRSUOIKOZ6XVMQW2NHHLZK", "offset": "96230370"}`

This is the url I'm attempting to use to download the warc for the record : https://aws-publicdatasets.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2015-11/segments/1424936462009.45/warc/CC-MAIN-20150226074102-00094-ip-10-28-5-156.ec2.internal.warc.gz

am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://aws.amazon.com/datasets/common-crawl-corpus/)...

> Available at: s3://aws-publicdatasets/common-crawl/

...it looks like you are missing a path-prefix of `/common-crawl`, so I'd suggest that the correct URL would be `https://aws-publicdatasets.s3.amazonaws.com/common-crawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2015-11/...`

Comment: so it was something fairly obvious. thanks for the help!